# I am trying to make a study reminder software but when the if the start value is as same as the hour variable it wont remind me

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, time, reminders

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

studyTime = True

root = tk.Tk()

while studyTime:
    #Hour variable
    hour = time.strftime("%H")

    #Study Time1
    studyTime_start1 = "18:00"
    studyTime_end1 = "19:00"

    #Study Time2
    studyTime_start2 = "18:00"
    studyTime_end2 = "20:00"

    if hour < studyTime_end1 and hour > studyTime_start1:
        Msg = tk.messagebox.showinfo(title = "Study Time", message = "Study Time")
        HW_checkBtn = ttk.Button(root, text = "Study Time Started Click Here to Start")
        HW_checkBtn.pack()
        studyTime = False

    if hour < studyTime_end2 and hour > studyTime_start2:
        Msg1 = tk.messagebox.showinfo(title = "Study Time1", message = "Study Time1")
        HW_checkBtn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "Study Time Started Click Here to Start")
        HW_checkBtn1.pack()
        studyTime = False

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It almost sounds like this could be fixed by using the `>=` operator?  Its hard to understand your issue.

Comment: Note that `'18' > '18:00'` is *False* if `hour` is `'18'`.  Even `'18' >= '18:00'` is *False*.

Comment: It looks like you will need the `strptime()` to convert the string to a datetime object before the conditions will work as expected.  [look at this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:~:text=classmethod%20datetime.strptime,and%20strptime()%20Behavior.)